# Heat equation mixed Neumann and Dirichlet Boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, heat-equation

The question gives that

$$u_{t}=Du_{xx}$$

where the boundaries are

IC: $$u(x,0)=0$$

BC1: $$u_x(L,t)=0$$

BC2: $$u(0,t)=C_0.$$

I have solved for the steady-state equation of for this, which equals to be $$u_{ss}(x)=C_0$$
and found that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_ncos(\frac{(n-1/2pi) x}{L})e^{D\frac{(n-1/2pi)}{L}^2t}$$

How do we solve for Bn in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v(x,t)=u(x,t)-C_0$. Then
$$
               v_t = u_t = Du_{xx}=Dv_{xx} \\
            v(x,0) = u(x,0)-C_0 = -C_0 \\
              v_x(L,t) = u_x(L,t) = 0 \\
              v(0,t) = u(0,t)-C_0 = 0.
$$
The homogeneous endpoint conditions in $x$ at $0,L$ work out great for separation of variables. The separated solutions have the form
$$
                v_n(x,t) = e^{-D(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t/L^2}\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/L),\;\; n=0,1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The general solution is
$$
        u(x,t)=C_0+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E_ne^{-D(n+1/2)^2\pi^2 t/L^2}\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/L).
$$
It is easy to verify that
$$
                 u_t = Du_{xx} \\
       u(0,t) = C_0 \\
       u_x(L,t) = 0 \\
       u(x,0) = C_0+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E_n\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/L)
$$
The constants $E_n$ are determined by the requirement that $u(x,0)=0$:
$$
         \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E_n\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/L)= - C_0.
$$
This can be accomplished on $(0,L)$, but not at the endpoints $x=0,L$, unless $C_0=0$. The constant function can be expressed as a sine series; the functions $\sin((n+1/2)\pi x/L)$ are mutually orthogonal on $[0,L]$ because of the Sturm-Liouville conditions where the functions vanish at $0$ and their first derivatives vanish at $L$. That determines the constants $E_n$.

Comment: Hey dear, why would the Eigenfunctions a sine function? Thanks!

Comment: I also got the same initial condition, and got Bm by using Euler’s method and intergrating the cosine eigenfunction. Which proves the answer was the same